# How to select folders from a directory based on a python list of the folder names?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, directory, operating-system

I have a list of folder names - "df_train_pos_list"

I want to iterate through a directory and select folders with those names, and add them to another list - "train_images"

So far what I have tried doesn't work:

```
train_images = []
train_labels = []

for i in df_train_pos_list:
    for currentpath, folders, files in os.walk('D:\Arm C Deep Learning\SH_OCTAPUS\Train'):
        for file in files:
            if i in currentpath:
                train_images.append('D:\Arm C Deep Learning\SH_OCTAPUS\Train' + file)
                train_labels.append(1)
            else:
                train_images.append('D:\Arm C Deep Learning\SH_OCTAPUS\Train' + file)
                train_labels.append(0)
train_labels = np.asarray(train_labels, dtype=np.int64)
print(train_labels)
np.unique(train_labels, return_counts='TRUE')
```

Answer (score 0):

Kind of unsure if you want to add folder path to the list or the individual files in the folder to your list but the below snippet will add the folder paths to your `trains_list`. would need more details on what you want out of the label to add that.

```
import os
df_train_pos_list =[]
train_images = []
#train_labels = []
root = 'D:\Arm C Deep Learning\SH_OCTAPUS\Train'
for f in os.listdir(root):
    if f in df_train_pos_list:
        train_label = 1
    else:
        train_label = 0
    train_images.append((os.path.join(root,f),train_label)) #this will add your folder file path to train images

for folder, label in train_images:
    if label==1:
        #do something here
```

Comment: Thank you. Basically, I would like all the folders in the directory to be added to "train_images" and if they are in "df_train_pos_list" I want their corresponding "train_label" to be "1", but if not, the label should be "0".

Comment: I tried: `root = 'D:\Arm C Deep Learning\SH_OCTAPUS\Train'
for f in os.listdir(root):
    if f in df_train_pos_list:
        train_images.append(os.path.join(root,f)) #this will add your folder file path to train images
        train_labels.append(1)
    else:
        train_images.append(os.path.join(root,f)) 
        train_labels.append(0)
train_labels = np.asarray(train_labels, dtype=np.int64)
print(train_labels)
np.unique(train_labels, return_counts='TRUE')` but it gave all folders a "0" label.

Comment: Why not create a list of tuples ('Folder name', 0) or ('Folder name',1) then parse that list of tuples and read the integer to do stuff. that way you have one list.  Editing my post to provide details.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, you are trying to generate 2 lists: one containing all the paths in "D:\Arm C Deep Learning\SH_OCTAPUS\Train" and one containing 0s and 1s depending on whether a path is in `df_train_pos_list`.

This should do the trick:

```py
from pathlib import Path

df_train_pos_list = []
train_images = []
train_labels = []
df_train_pos_set = set(df_train_pos_list)

for path in Path("D:\Arm C Deep Learning\SH_OCTAPUS\Train").glob("*"):
    train_images.append(path)
    train_labels.append(1 if path.name in df_train_pos_set else 0)
```

A couple things to note:

- `pathlib` is best practice when dealing with the file system.
- I'm creating a `set` from your `df_train_pos_list` to improve complexity. It will take O(N) time complexity to create the `set` from the `list` but it will take O(1) to check whether a path is in the `set` whereas it would take O(N) using a `list`.

Comment: Thank you for your advice and sorry if my question wasn't clear. You are correct - basically I want all the folders to be in the list "train_images" and I want their corresponding "train_labels" to be "1" if they are in df_train_pos_list or "0" if not. Your suggestion almost works but it is giving all folders a "0" label. Do you know why this could be?

Comment: @sum87 my answer does exactly that. Check that your `df_train_pos_list` contains valid paths. You can do so by doing something like `f"D:\Arm C Deep Learning\SH_OCTAPUS\Train\{filename}" in df_train_pos_list `.

Comment: Ahh. Thanks Alexandre - my `df_train_pos_list` just contains the folder names e.g. `['folder 1', 'folder 2']` etc. Is there a way I can just use the folder names to make this work, or do I have to join the entire file path to the folder names in the list first?

Comment: @sum87 I updated my answer, now it should work as expected. You need to be more precise when you ask a question :)